# How we can detect lists and tables in a PDF?

Tags: pdf, itext, adobe, accessibility, pdfbox

When I used autotagging option in Adobe it is auto detecting lists and tables and tagging it. How it know is it a list, table , Image and paragraph. How It is accurately detecting?

Now I have to detect like same in my PDF by using code. And I tried to detect using content stream information, There is no clue I found.

This will be so helpful to me. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't know how Adobe Acrobat knows it. The options coming to my mind are: **A)**   Render the page in question as bitmap and apply image based table recognition (you get a number of articles and projects when you google that). **B)** Analyze PDFs from many different PDF generators and look for typical structures in the content stream instructions used to generate lists and tables. - Of course one might want to combine those options.

Comment: There is a huge project that does something similar: Tabula. And there's that new amazon service, Amazon Textract, so you're probably reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

1. For tagged PDF documents you should browse the document StructTree. It contains a reference to each table or list in the document. Reading the struct tree is possible with many pdf tools for example pdfix (the free version). An example of how to do that in Python [How can I extract all PDF Tags related to content with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63189254/how-can-i-extract-all-pdf-tags-related-to-content-with-python/76209538#76209538)
2. Non-tagged PDF documents have to be processed with an object detection algorithm. An object detection AI model can be used like in this example https://github.com/pdfix/pdfix-autotag-deepdoctection or directly using the https://pdfix.io/scrape-pdf-data/ with its internal detection algorithm for logical content extraction.